# How to get WI-FI signal strength in percantage from Scan Network?

Tags: java, android, wifi, rssi

I need to Scan Wifi Networks.

How can i `getRssi()` of WiFi Scan Network (Not of connection wi-fi network)

```
        int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifi.getConnectionInfo().getRssi(),
                        results.get(i).level);
                int difference = level * 100 / results.get(i).level;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok try this to find signal strength

```
    WifiManager manager;
    manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    List<ScanResult> results = manager.getScanResults();
    int level = getPowerPercentage(results.get(0).level);//0 for first scan result and so on.
```

Method to find signal stength

```
    public int getPowerPercentage(int power) {
    int i = 0;
    int MIN_DBM = -100;
    if (power <= MIN_DBM) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i = 100 + power;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Hope this ll help you.

Comment: Method return very low values. I don't sure that is true. But Maybe we need something like this 

`int level = 100 - getPowerPercentage(results.get(0).level);`